# Pandas to_csv raising IOError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am scraping and writing `df` to csv like this.

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@class="table-main detail-odds sortable"]').get_attribute('outerHTML')
df = pd.read_html(table)[0]
row_drop = df[df['Bookmakers'].str.contains("Highest", na=False)].index.tolist()
df = df.iloc[:row_drop[0]+1]
df.insert(0,'Name', f'{name}')
df.insert(1,'Date', f'{date}')
df.insert(2,'Result',f'{result}')
df[['Name', 'Date', 'Result']] = df[['Name', 'Date','Result']].mask(df.duplicated(subset=['Name', 'Date', 'Result']), '')
fullname =f'{name}.csv'
outdir = './Tennis'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)
fullname = os.path.join(outdir, fullname)
df.to_csv(fullname, index=False)
```

However, it writes 10 files and then throws this error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> './Tennis\El Allami F-Z./Mecchi C. - Perrin C./Shrivastava A.csv'

Nothing is changing scraping wise. I tried the other method suggested

```
from pathlib import Path

output_file = 'my_file.csv'
output_dir = Path('long_path/to/my_dir')

output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

df.to_csv(output_dir / output_file)  # can join path elements with / operator
```

This gives `exist_ok` as an `unexpected_argument`. On removing this..I get the same error. Where is this going wrong?

**info** :- 10 is the number of links on the first page. It gets 1 csv for each page. So, the driver opens another page with another of set links where it fails on the first link. I don't know what this could have to do with it.

Comment: Is this the only file (or first file program encounters) to have `/` in the file name? My guess is it's trying to create a file named `Shrivastava A.csv` in a `./Tennis\El Allami F-Z./Mecchi C. - Perrin C./` folder, while the code suggests the file name is `El Allami F-Z./Mecchi C. - Perrin C./Shrivastava A.csv`

Comment: It is simply writing to a folder called `Tennis` .That `El Allami F-Z./Mecchi C. - Perrin C./Shrivastava A.` is in fact the name of the match on the site...I guess that is it.

Answer (score 1):

The path `fullname` might have non-existing directories in it. Make sure you create intermediate directories, using `os.makedirs`:

```
fullname =f'{name}.csv'
outdir = './Tennis'
filepath = os.path.join(outdir, fullname)
# Create the full directory tree, if needed:
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filepath), exist_ok=True)

df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: @dm2 was right. `t1 = name.replace('/', '')
    t1 = t1.replace('.', '')` ..This solved it.

Comment: Yes my solution is for another need as yours, it seems. I was assuming you wanted to preserve the original file hierarchy.

Comment: I didn't know that the match name was having these characters. Otherwise, simple `df.to_csv(f'/tennis/{name}.csv)` was working fine.

Comment: Your error suggests that you had instances with `/`s inside `name`, thus it tried to access a folder that didn't exist. (`El Allami F-Z./Mecchi C. - Perrin C./` in your example error). That's also why deleting the `/`s, as dm2 suggested, also works. It will create the csv files in the `C:/tennis`, without the `/` in the exhaustive names. It depends on what you need.

Comment: Also, `exist_ok` is a parameter to `os.makedirs` method, not to `os.mkdir`.