# How to open a local file on Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm writing a Python code with colab, and I want to read a csv stored in my computer.
Here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\Alen\Downloads\price.csv',header=1)
```

The error message is shown below:

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Alen\\Downloads\\price.csv'
```

However, I am sure the file is in this directory, and I already tried lots of formats to write the directory.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @HampusLarsson The way you answer to the question is unfaithful to the author. This community is supposed to give useful advice on the question but not to treat it lightheartedly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas to\_csv raising IOError: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68022006/pandas-to-csv-raising-ioerror-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Sorry, I might not describe my question clearly, but there is actually a file called price.csv, and I'm not sure how to fix the directory problem after trying several of formats to set the directory.

Comment: @ting_H Please note that answers shouldn't be posted inside the question. Any answer should be posted below. I converted your answer to a Community Wiki below. If you wish to post it yourself, ping me here (with `@Tomerikoo`) and I'll delete the CW answer

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Answer originally posted [as part of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69698539/3):</sup>

---

I tried the  same code on the spyder, and it can work.
So I guess the problem is because I run the program on the google colab, which function on the google server, but the file is in the local desktop.

---

The solution is to upload the file to the google drive, but NOT BY SIMPLY UPLOAD THE FILE!

The picture is how I uploaded my file successfully.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check them out below:

1. Did you mistype 'C:\Users\Alen\Downloads\ **\** price.csv'?
2. Try using slash instead of backslash; it's common to use the former literal to specify paths on jupyter notebook

Comment: I tried 

`C:\Users\Alen\Downloads\\price.csv`
`C:\Users\Alen\Downloads\price.csv`
`C:/Users/Alen/Downloads//price.csv`
`C:/Users/Alen/Downloads/price.csv`
But none of these could work, still thank you for helping!

Comment: @ting_H
I'm afraid I myself have a typo... 'C:/' should be 'C://' instead

Comment: I found another way to figure it out! Still a lot of thanks :D